# dataTables.js conflicting with fileInput.js

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I've a codeigniter project with neon admin panel. 
I need to add dataTable.js and fileInput.js plugins. But when i use fileInput.js it comes up with this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $this.bootstrapFileInput is not a function
```

I've these script added. If I remove fileInput.js than all works fine.

```
<script src="assets/js/selectboxit/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/datatables/datatables.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/select2/select2.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/typeahead.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/icheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/neon-chat.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/fileinput.js"></script>
```

Can anyone please help me on that?

Comment: this happens to me once with other plugins. Check that only one jquery is loaded to the app. For example with datatables it's possible that you download a version with jquery, so jquery is loaded twice. Hope it helps.

Comment: @andre_vieira I've checked it. also, I've provided the script list. Can you look and tell if there is any repetition?

Comment: the repetition can be inside one of that script. For example in datatables it's possible that the file contains the jquery + datatables script. But just a guest.

Comment: another think that you can try is reorder the import of scripts to check if any of them is conflicting originating that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it. Don't know if it cause any problem in future.
I've just used `dataTable.js` inside head after `jQuery`.

If in future I come up with any error that I'll surely let you know.